# Использование кнопки "Назад" телефона в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: javascript, popup

На некоторых телефонах под Android'ом присутствует физическая кнопка "назад". В случае нажатия данной кнопки при просмотре веб-страницы на телефоне, обычно мы возвращаемся на предыдущую страницу.
Возможно ли привязать данную кнопку к функции закрытия pop-up окна на сайте. Так как неудобно, когда вместо закрытия окна, страница полностью перезагружается.
Спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужно решение только на Андроид? Я могу предложить решение для все устройств?

Comment: С удовольствием приму ваш совет, это же просто замечательно)

Comment: Написал ответ, попробуйте. Так делал довольно давно, и возможно какой-то шаг забыл, но думаю +/- будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

При окрытии модально окна с помощью `window.history.pushState` добавить к URL хеш, например `#popup` (это сэмулирует переход на другую страницу, но при этом не перезагрузит страницу) и создать слушетеля события смены URL:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
  ...
}, false);
```

И в этом обработчеке закрыть popup и удалить сам обработчик.